# Unable to save components -Intermittent issue - SDL Web 8.1

Tags: web8, content-manager, component

We are facing an issue in our Production environment while saving the components below error is coming intermittently.

Sometime Components gets saved but sometimes below error is coming, anyone has any idea? Till now i have done restart of CME instance, checked my DB connections and Timeout settings, but dint resolve this issue.

```
    A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ORG_ITEMS.FINDUNIQUENESSCONFLICTS".
ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
ORA-06512: at "TCMDBUSER.EDA_ORG_ITEMS", line 3983
ORA-06512: at line 1
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 831 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, Nullable`1 commandBehavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, Nullable`1 commandBehavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflicts(TcmUri orgItemId, TcmUri refItemId, IEnumerable`1 properties)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.GetConflicts(IEnumerable`1 values, Boolean ignoreSelfConflicts, Repository contextRepository, OrganizationalItem organizationalItem)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IEnumerable`1 propertiesToCheck, Boolean ignoreSelfConflicts)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IEnumerable`1 propertiesToCheck)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Save(IdentifiableObjectData deltaData, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
   at SyncInvokeSave(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Please refer to this link https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=Intermittent-ORA-01013-exception-when-saving-an-item-in-SDL-Tridion-2013-SP1 is for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 may be you can check if its the same case with your version. Since  8.1 is old version and you need to check if you still have support

Comment: do you have DB maintenance tasks scheduled? If not, run sp_updatestats on CM DB

Comment: Neel did you get a chance to fix the issue  if so  can you update the answer.